# How to properly write a SET DATE

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I'm creating a function were I provide 3 inputs @FiscalYEar, @StartDate, @EndDate,  I also declare a DATE parameter that the year will be -1 of @FiscalYear

```
SET @fyLowerBound = OCT 1 OF (@FiscalYear - 1)
```

how do I properly write the SET statement to make it work?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Looks like SQL Server?

Comment: The answer depends on the database engine and a unit of measurement for -1, neither of which you provided.

Comment: SQL Server 2008, sorry for not including that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
DECLARE @FiscalYear INT = 2014,
        @fyLowerBound DATE;

SET @fyLowerBound = CAST(CAST((@FiscalYear - 1) AS CHAR(4)) + '1001' AS DATE)

SELECT  @fyLowerBound;
```

This gives 1st October 2013.

The premise being creating a string date in the format `yyyyMMdd`, in SQL Server this is the only culture insensitive date for DATETIME (yyyy-MM-dd will work for DATE), you then cast that string to a date (or datetime whatever your preference).

So the first step is to turn your integer date into a `CHAR(4)`, you can then create october 1st of this year by concatenating `'1001'`. You now have a string that will be cast to a date.

Answer (score 0):

```
SET @fyLowerBound = DATEADD(yy, -1, @FiscalYear)
```

This will give you a date that's a year less than @FiscalYear. Although I'm not entirely sure this is what you need, given that 'OCT' in your original statement.